# Rails: Take embed code and get video URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a rails library for taking embed code and returning the url of the video?

for example, if I pass the following:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/J---aiyznGQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it will return

```
www.youtube.com/embed/J---aiyznGQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the video id using a regular expression and then use that to generate the url.

Here is a good link for the regex: https://gist.github.com/afeld/1254889

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
embed_code = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/J---aiyznGQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
regex = /(youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(watch\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v)\/))([^\?&"'>]+)/

youtube_id = embed_code.match(regex)[5]

'www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtube_id 
#=> www.youtube.com/embed/J---aiyznGQ
```